# ¿Someone can explain to me Callback in JavaScript? - beginner

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, callback

i im a beginner in this world and i feel like a im a little bit loset in thist.

i buy a course in udemy and this is the example:

```
function add( a, b, cb) {
    const r = a + b 
    cb(r)
}

function callback(result) {
    console.log('This is the result', result);
}

add(2, 3, callback)
```

This is the part i dont understand:
cb(r) -
¿Why the "cb" are in that part of my code (add(a,b,**cb**)) and repeat later?
i undestan we save the result of const r in Cb(r) but i dont know why is in both parts

¿Why when i run this in my terminal it came callback function firts and add function?

if someone can i explain to me what are happen here step by step i goint to appreciate it

i just whant to know how this works because its sound like is important on this path, it runs but i dont know why

Comment: The example seems to introduce how you can pass a function reference (`callback`) as an argument to another function, and then call the passed function. If you'd extend the example with another declared function, and called `add(2, 3, anotherCallback)`, you'll find out how this pattern could be used. It also makes possible to call the declared functions alone outside of `add`.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which you wrote **function add** and **function callback** doesn't matter. They're just definitions, i.e. recipes on how to do something. But unless they're called, nothing is actually done by just writing functions.

By writing **function add( a, b, cb)**, you just say "*I am writing a function named add, which is expected to receive 3 parameters as an input, and I name them a, b and cb.*" But you don't know yet what their value is. You just name them this way in order to be able to do things with them. When you call **cb(r)** you have basically no idea what cb is, you just know it's a function to be completed later.

Basically your code is not going to be executed in the order in which you wrote it.

Javascript starts doing things when it reads **add(2, 3, callback)**. At this point it understands that it needs to execute **function add**, to which you've given three parameters, two of which are number and the third one is a function. But it doesn't execute the **function callback** yet, it just knows its name. For now it's just going to search into your code where the **function add** is and execute this one first, with **a=2, b=3, and cb=callback**.

Once it found it, jumps to the beginning of the **function add**, creates a new **constant r** and puts **a+b** in it. When it sees **Cb(r)**, it takes your third parameter that you've submitted to it, in this case the **function callback**, and calls it with parameter **r**. So again, it jumps to the beginning of function callback and executes it with parameter **r**.

In this example, there is no need to use a callback function, that's just a basic exemple to illustrate the concept of callbacks. But as said in the comments of your post, you may want to write a second callback function, such as :

```js
function anotherCallback(result) {
    console.log('This is ANOTHER result', result);
}
```

And then you could call

```js
add(2, 3, callback)
add(4, 5, anotherCallback)
```

without having to re-write the function add.

I've tried to make it as detailed as possible, I hope this is clear but if not don't hesitate to ask further questions.